# Асинхронный роут выполняется не совсем асинхронно

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio

Цель:

Запустить функцию `bm()` асинхронно для с помощью `TaskFactory`. Ну и после запуска вычитывать прогресс выполнения.

Проблема:

Код полностью работает. Проблема в асинхронности. Ставлю точку на `return` в роуте и прохожу его до того как функция `bm()` закончит выполенние. Но в другом софте (где ожидаю ответ) результат приходит только после выполнения функции `bm()`

Роут:

```
@app.route('/api/startMerge', methods= ['POST'])
async def big_merge():
    res = None
    try:
        res = await taskFactory.startTask(request)
        return res
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return '', 400

@app.route('/api/getMergeStatus', methods= ['POST'])
def get_merge_status():
    id = request.values['id']
    return taskFactory.getStatus(id)
```

Менеджер тасков:

```
class TaskFactory:
    operations = []
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    async def startTask(self, request):
        try:
            operation = Operation()
            # asyncio.create_task(bm(request, operation.setStatus))
            asyncio.gather(bm(request, operation.setStatus))
            self.operations.append(operation)
            return {
                'Status': 'success',
                'Value': operation.id
            }
        except Exception as e:
              return {
                'Status': 'error',
                'Value': str(e)
            }
        
    def getStatus(self, id):
        obj = next(filter(lambda x: x.id == id, self.operations), None)
        if obj is not None:
            return {
                'Status': obj.status,
                'Message': obj.message,
                'ProgressValue': obj.progressValue,
                'Object': obj.object
            }
        else:
            return None
```

Функция:

```
   async def bm(request, changeStatusFunc = None):
      .....
```

Comment: А что у вас внутри функции bm() ? она там хоть await делает ? ведь асинхронность работает только если функцию можно прервать в точке с await

Comment: @Mike await заставляет ждать, если функция асинхронная. Функция bm() асинхронная, но внутри нет await, т к внутри идет просто синхронный код. Мне не важно когда он закончится. мне главное его запустить, и пойти дальше

Comment: нет, await не просто заставляет ждать, но и именно в этой точке отдает управление (т.е. процессор) основному циклу ожидания событий, который ищет готовую к выполнению задачу и запускает ее. Если await нет то ваша функция не отдает никому процессор и весь асинхронный механизм не работает. Это же асинхронность, а не многопоточность, у вас только один поток процессора, пока процессор занят, никто не может выполняться параллельно

Comment: @Mike 1. Дайте плз что-то предметное почитать (где будет описываться суть..можно англ.). 2. Ну окей. но мне не нужно ожидание. Тогда я не понимаю зачем в моей функции юзать await и на что его юзать если в ней сплошной синхрон. И я вижу что она выполняется.

Comment: Асинхрон в принципе нужно в случаях когда у вас есть что то, что может ждать внешних событий, не используя при этом процессор. И почти все такие ситуации - это ожидания сети. Если у вас нечего ждать снаружи и нужен только процессор и надолго, то вам надо функцию отправлять в другой поток. Для этого можно например использовать asyncio run_in_executor() или to_thread() https://habr.com/ru/companies/wunderfund/articles/710190/

Comment: Так как у вас тут походу fast api то в нем Depends умеют так работать. Если вы в fast api делаете не async роут или используете в качестве Depend синхронной функции, находясь в объявлении асинхронной, то fast api под капотом сам выполняет их через run_in_executor

Comment: @Mike спасибо больше за ваши комментарии. Они мне достаточно помогли. Получилсоь все решить с помощью мультипроцесинга и расшаренных списков

Comment: расшаренные списки капец какие медленные.

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронные функции работают в том месте где написано `await`. Если bm делает много легких операций - вставь между операциями `await asyncio.sleep(0)`. Если bm тяжелая, то обязательно выполнение через `run_in_executor` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools